# Is there any query to fetch the a single row data in chunks?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

The data stored in a row is just like `"Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- MISSED Call Date:--- 2013-06-13 Call duration in sec :--- 0 Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- OUTGOING Call Date:--- 2013-06-14 Call duration in sec :--- 21 Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- INCOMING Call Date:--- 2013-06-14 Call duration in sec :--- 79"`.

Is there any query that may help me to retrieve this row in parts or chunks.

Comment: Your example shows three "sets" of data in the one row; will there always be three?  Can you change the formatting at all (to put a delimiter between the "sets", or between the fields?

Comment: Yes, i have done almost the same thing that you've said. Before the Phone Number, i have put # symbol so that i can differentiate between the records.

Comment: And thnx for the reply, i followed this...and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a while on your request dude... your problem is that it's not really adapted for relational database **(POOR PERFORMANCES)**, you will be obliged to use some scripting language, but there is some interesting results:

I've created a tale with one line:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn VARCHAR(1000));
```

Inserted your example in it:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ("Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- MISSED Call Date:--- 2013-06-13 Call duration in sec :--- 0 Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- OUTGOING Call Date:--- 2013-06-14 Call duration in sec :--- 21 Phone Number:--- xxxxxxxxxxx Call Type:--- INCOMING Call Date:--- 2013-06-14 Call duration in sec :--- 79");
```

Now with my query you can retrieve one line in your dataset. This query will split the result and return one line, you just have to modify the @i variable to choose your line (0 is the first line) :

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 3),' ', -1) AS "Phone Number",
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 6),' ', -1) AS "Phone Type",
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 9),' ', -1) AS "Call Date", 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 15),' ', -1) AS "Call Duration in sec"
FROM mytable;
```

Example with the third line:

```
[11:42:02] [DEV\MFO] mysql> SET @i=2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

[11:42:08] [DEV\MFO] mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 3),' ', -1) AS "Phone Number", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 6),' ', -1) AS "Phone Type", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 9),' ', -1) AS "Call Date",  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ' ', (@i * 15) + 15),' ', -1) AS "Call Duration in sec" FROM mytable;
+--------------+------------+------------+----------------------+
| Phone Number | Phone Type | Call Date  | Call Duration in sec |
+--------------+------------+------------+----------------------+
| xxxxxxxxxxx  | INCOMING   | 2013-06-14 | 79                   |
+--------------+------------+------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that if you want to know how many lines you have in your dataset you can use:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(mycolumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(mycolumn, ' ', '')) + 1) / 15 FROM mytable;
```

Let me know...

Max.